# Android Volley POST Sending Parameters is always null

Tags: android, post, android-volley

I am new in android.Now i am doing one application.For this one i need to send data  into server.Now i am using Volley post method.But the parameters is always shows null when i send data into server using volley.here i attached the code please check it.Here i am using fragments.

**Code Section**

```
String url = "http://192.168.1.182:8084/name/registration.jsp";

    final ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this.getActivity());
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();    
    RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST,
            url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
            // pDialog.hide();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            //pDialog.hide();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("name", "Ajay K K");
            params.put("mailid", "ajaykk50@gmail.com");
            params.put("phone", "8086327023");
            params.put("place", "Calicut");
            params.put("longitude","44444.3333");
            params.put("latitude","666666.3333");
            params.put("wheel", "1");
            params.put("type", "owner");

            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    rq.add(jsonObjReq);
```

Answer (score 8):

Don't override `getParams()`. `JsonObjectRequest` uses third argument in constructor to get post parameters. below is documentation contained in volley's code

```
/**
 * Creates a new request.
 * @param method the HTTP method to use
 * @param url URL to fetch the JSON from
 * @param jsonRequest A {@link JSONObject} to post with the request. Null is allowed and
 *   indicates no parameters will be posted along with request.
 * @param listener Listener to receive the JSON response
 * @param errorListener Error listener, or null to ignore errors.
 */
public JsonObjectRequest(int method, String url, JSONObject jsonRequest,
        Listener<JSONObject> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(method, url, (jsonRequest == null) ? null : jsonRequest.toString(), listener,
                errorListener);
}
```

uses like this.

```
String url = "http://192.168.1.182:8084/name/registration.jsp";

final ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this.getActivity());
pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
pDialog.show();    
RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
try {
    params.put("name", "Ajay K K");
    params.put("mailid", "ajaykk50@gmail.com");
    params.put("phone", "8086327023");
    params.put("place", "Calicut");
    params.put("longitude","44444.3333");
    params.put("latitude","666666.3333");
    params.put("wheel", "1");
    params.put("type", "owner");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST,
        url, params, //Not null.
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
        // pDialog.hide();
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        //pDialog.hide();
    }
});

// Adding request to request queue
rq.add(jsonObjReq);
```

Comment: Worked for me. But i think that is depending on web service implementation.

Comment: this will give data in body instead of req.params

Answer (score 2):

```
import com.android.volley.NetworkResponse;
import com.android.volley.ParseError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener;
import com.android.volley.Response.Listener;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpHeaderParser;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Map;

public class CustomRequest extends Request<JSONObject> {

private Listener<JSONObject> listener;
private Map<String, String> params;

public CustomRequest(String url, Map<String, String> params,
                     Listener<JSONObject> reponseListener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(Method.GET, url, errorListener);
    this.listener = reponseListener;
    this.params = params;
}

public CustomRequest(int method, String url, Map<String, String> params,
                     Listener<JSONObject> reponseListener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(method, url, errorListener);
    this.listener = reponseListener;
    this.params = params;
}

protected Map<String, String> getParams()
        throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
    return params;
}

;

@Override
protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
        String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
        return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString),
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    } catch (JSONException je) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
    }
}

@Override
protected void deliverResponse(JSONObject response) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    listener.onResponse(response);
    }
}
```

*After That Call This Class From Your Activity...LIKE THIS*

```
 RequestQueue requestQueue = VolleySingleton.getInstance().getRequestQueue();
        CustomRequest jsObjRequest = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_URL, params, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d("RESPONSE", response.toString());

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d("RESPONSE ERROR", "Error: " + error.getMessage());

            }
        });

        requestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
```

*You can create params as*

```
 Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("email", "yourEmail");
        params.put("password", "yourPassword");
```

**Other Classes you need are "VolleySingleton" and "RetriveMyApplicationContext"**

```
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.util.LruCache;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;


public class VolleySingleton {

private static VolleySingleton sInstance = null;
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private ImageLoader imageLoader;

private VolleySingleton() {
    mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RetriveMyApplicationContext.getAppContext());

    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {

        private LruCache<String, Bitmap> cache = new LruCache<>((int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024 / 8));

        @Override
        public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
            return cache.get(url);
        }

        @Override
        public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
            cache.put(url, bitmap);
        }
    });

}

public static VolleySingleton getInstance() {
    if (sInstance == null) {
        sInstance = new VolleySingleton();
    }
    return sInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    return mRequestQueue;
}

public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
    return imageLoader;
}
}
```

**RetriveMyApplicationContext Class**

```
public class RetriveMyApplicationContext extends Application {


//Don't forget to mention RetriveMyApplicationContext Class in Manifests File otherwise it will throw NullPointer Exception
// <application
// android:name=".volley.RetriveMyApplicationContext"


private static RetriveMyApplicationContext mRetriveMyApplicationContext;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mRetriveMyApplicationContext = this;
}

public static RetriveMyApplicationContext getInstance() {

    return mRetriveMyApplicationContext;
}

public static Context getAppContext() {

    return mRetriveMyApplicationContext.getApplicationContext();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the easy way for me is to add parms manually to url string
and i call it from php page with $_GET['benes']

```
String url ="https://progromatic.online/accounta/api/getbee.php?benes="+benefs.getText();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class CustomJsonRequest extends Request {

Map<String, String> params;       
private Response.Listener listener; 

public CustomJsonRequest(int requestMethod, String url, Map<String, String> params,
                      Response.Listener responseListener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {

    super(requestMethod, url, errorListener);
    this.params = params;
    this.listener = responseListener;
}

@Override
protected void deliverResponse(Object response) {
    listener.onResponse(response); 

}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
         return params;
}

@Override
protected Response parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
        String jsonString = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
        return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString),
        HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    } catch (JSONException je) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Could you add a few lines to explain your answer ? Thanks.

Comment: U copied this answer, u should not do that,

Answer (score -2):

I am also faced this type of error i wasted half day to solve this.Finally i solved.

It is not Android code problem,check parameters what u send to server and check columns in database.If columns not found in database that we get this error.